# Using REST API, I am trying to send an email to a list (not a Triggered Send). I seem to be having trouble, can you help?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, fuel, node.js

I want to "Schedule a send using the Send API” (REST) I was following the documentation, but it was removed around 7/6/2016. Is this not possible using rest anymore?

I was implementing "Schedule an integrated send using the given definition.” but the page was removed as well. I was hoping to follow the doc "Send Your Email to Your List”. I searched: Fuel SDKs & Fuel APIs but it seems that that functionality has been removed for rest, is this the case?

- Under "Fuel SDKs, the only “Send” option is for “Triggered Sends”, how do I send an email to a list without using Triggered Sends?
- I have implemented the following libraries and they are working well: FuelSDK-Node (fuel-soap, fuel-rest, fuel-auth). They help with everything up to the point of sending the email. I am using them to send Triggered emails, but I also need to send user-initiated emails as well.

Here is a non-working attempt at what was in the documentation previously:

```
mcloudTools.messageDefinitionSend = function() {

    var restOptions  = {
        auth: {
            clientId: process.env.MCLOUD_CLIENTID
            , clientSecret: process.env.MCLOUD_SECRET
        }
        // , origin: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com' // default --> https://www.exacttargetapis.com
    };

    var sendId = '2177425';
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/integration/send/salesforce/' + sendId + '/schedule',

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        json: {
            "Schedule": {
                "StartImmediately": true,
                "AllRecipientsOptedIn": true
            }
        }
    };


    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        var RestClient = new FuelRest(restOptions);
        return RestClient
            .post(options)
            .then(function(response) {
                fulfill(response);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });

    });
};
```

Here is my triggered send, this works fine, what I need is a process for sending an email to a list or a User-Initiated email.

```
mcloudTools.messageDefinitionSends = function(options) {

    // var options = {
    //     uri: '/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/' + 'key:' + sendKey + '/send',
    //
    //     headers: {
    //         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    //     },
    //     json: {
    //         "From": {
    //             "Address": fromAddress,
    //             "Name": "Sender"
    //         },
    //         "To": {
    //             "Address": 'first.last@company.com'
    //             , "SubscriberKey": "SDKSubscriberDS"
    //             , "ContactAttributes": {
    //                 "SubscriberAttributes": {
    //                     "ConversionReferenceId": req.attributes.uuid_card_url
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         }
    //         , "OPTIONS": {
    //             "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    //         }
    //     }
    // };

    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        var restOptions  = {
            auth: {
                clientId: process.env.MCLOUD_CLIENTID
                , clientSecret: process.env.MCLOUD_SECRET
            }
            // , origin: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com' // default --> https://www.exacttargetapis.com
        };
        var RestClient = new FuelRest(restOptions);
        return RestClient
            .post(options)
            .then(function(response) {
                fulfill(response);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });

    });
};
```

[image: Integrated Send was removed]

Comment: Instead of calling out the lack of documentation, can you post what you've done so far in regards to sending to a list via API?  You're unlikely to get any help with your question in its current form.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the feedback, I edited the question. The problem is, it is very difficult to write code that hits an api that is undocumented. My question is around writing specific code for the REST api. There was documentation, but it was recently removed, therefore, I can't write much code. Perhaps those api routes have been removed? I have no idea, that is why I posted this question. I'm not complaining about it, I am asking if that functionality is gone, if so then any code that is posted is useless.

Answer (score 0):

List Based send using C#, Java, or SOAP using the Send object:
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-send-object.html